# Multi-level Unmarshall JSON with changing key values

Tags: go, struct, unmarshalling

I've seen a few posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794336/golang-unmarshall-json-with-changing-key-value) that address the issue of unmarshalling on different keys. However, I seem to have a hard time figuring out how to do it when I have multiple layers.

Here is what I'd like to unmarshall:

`{"chainlink":{"usd":3.75}}`
However both `chainlink` and `usd` could be different.

My current approach looks like this:

```
type cryptoCurrency struct {
    Currency cryptoCurrencyResult `json: "chainlink,JPY,gold,apple"`
}

type cryptoCurrencyResult struct {
    Usd float64 `json: "usd,USDT,peso"`
}
```

(the above is obviously wrong)

And then using them:

```
var crypto cryptoCurrency
json.Unmarshal(data, &crypto)
```

But again, the data could look anything like:

```
{"chainlink":{"usd":3.75}}
{"JPY":{"USDT":1000}}
{"gold":{"peso":100}}
{"apple":{"usd":1.35}}
```

The current solutions on SO seem to be towards single level unmarshalling.

Comment: You can provide *exactly one* name for a JSON field in the struct tag. You also *cannot* include a space between the tag namespace and the value (i.e `json: "thing"` must be `json:"thing"`). It seems likely what you want here is a `map`, not a `struct`.

Comment: If you're guaranteed that there is a two level mapping, you can unmarshal into a map of maps. If you are guaranteed a single level of mapping you can unmarshal into `map[string]interface{}` and inspect, or use `json.RawMessage`.

Comment: Thanks guys! These could I have been answers instead of comments. The answer is a combination of torek , Adrian, and Tarun. I didn't know you could unmarshal into a map, so I was able to unmarshal them into a `map[string]map[string]float64`

Answer (score 1):

Some of my assumptions/suggestions:

1. You should not lose the data about the type of crypto i.e., whether it was chainlink, JPY, gold, or apple.
2. You will probably also need to take the currency into account and then convert everything into a standard currency in your program. (I have taken USD as the standard in my solution)
3. I have also assumed that your JSON structure is limited to what you've shown in the example. If there are more keys, the solution will (of course) change a little.

You can use a custom unmarshal for the struct, like the following:

```
type cryptoCurrency struct {
    Type       string
    PriceInUSD float64
}

func (c *cryptoCurrency) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var tmp map[string]map[string]float64
    json.Unmarshal(data, &tmp)
    for k, v := range tmp {
        c.Type = k
        switch {
        case v["usd"] != 0.0:
            c.PriceInUSD = v["usd"]
        case v["USDT"] != 0.0:
            // Convert into USD... same for peso
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here is the working example in [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6sp9LA_G2qO).